# when does Lie group homomorphism preserve the Haar measure?

Tags: lie-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group and $f:G\rightarrow G$ be a Lie group homomorphism such that $df_{e}$, the derivative of $f$ at the identity element $e$, satisfies $|\rm{det}\;df_{e}|=1$. If $\mu$ is a Haar measure on $G$, is it necessarily true that $f$ preserves the measure $\mu$?

Comment: What do you mean by "the" Haar measure? In general (left) Haar measures are only unique up to a multiplciative constant. If $G$ is compact, we can say there is a unique Haar measure $\mu$ such that $\int_Gd\mu=1$, but otherwise there isn't a standard choice.

Comment: Hi Kajelad, thanks for your reply. I have edited the question.

Comment: If you mean $f$ "preserves" $\mu$ in the sense that $f^*\omega=\pm\omega$ where $\omega$ is the associated volume form, then the answer is yes. If instead you mean $f_*\mu=\mu$, then the answer is yes in the compact case, but not so clear in the noncompact case. You can at least conclude that $f$ is a covering map and $f_*\mu$ is *a* Haar measure.